# How do I run older Flutter Project that has Gradle build errors?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to running a pretty old Flutter project within these version:

```
Flutter 1.22.6
Dart 2.10.5
Java 1.8.0_321
Android Studio 2021.2.1
```

And for whatever reason, after I update my Android Studio (I don't event know if this is related), I cant't running my project properly with this error below:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0, 16.0.99].
     Required by:
         project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/'.
                  > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0].
     Required by:
         project :app > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And my `flutter doctor -v` is also weird not detecting the Android Studio's Dart & Flutter plugins for whatever reason as well. Here is the result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/permanar/flutter-1.22.6
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (1 year, 4 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/permanar/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/permanar/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.


[!] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

No matter what I use (AS or VSCode), it's basically the same.

This is my `app\build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oende.octo_certification_manager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7'
    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
//    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Could any mobile developers experts help me please?

Comment: It looks like you will want to go into Android Studio, then go to the main menu -> Preferences -> Plugins and make sure you have Flutter up to date, and see where that gets you.

Note: The gradle version used by the app is specified in the project build.gradle file, not the one under app/

Comment: @eimmer I have checked the plugins up-to-date. If I change the Flutter version (to the latest or somewhat around it), it would been a green check. I think there's a bug with the `flutter doctor`. Anyway, do you have any solutions for me, sir?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the top-level `build.gradle` (the directory above `app/`), you will probably see something like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

JCenter has [been shut down](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) and isn't fully operational, so you will need to migrate off it. Most of the dependencies are probably available on Maven Central; this is true for `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk` and `io.grpc:grpc-core`. Dependencies like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` are available in the [Google repository](https://maven.google.com). Thus a more recent project would use:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

However, you may be using a version of Gradle before `google()` was added. You can upgrade your Gradle version, but you can also explicitly define the location of the repository until you do so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```